# flutter - widget with transparent background

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am creating a StatefulWidget which have a transparent background. Code for same is:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Builder(
    builder: (context) => Material(
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.75),
          child: new SafeArea(
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    resetPasswordLabel,
                    inputFields,
                    doneButton(context),
                  ],
                ),
                height: 250.0,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
  ),
);
```

**Problem:** When I am opening this widget using Navigator the transparent color is visible for 1 - 2 seconds and after it turns to the black background.

Output:
[image]

Accepted Output should be:
[image]

Please assist me here.

Comment: did you find a way?

Comment: check [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54572108)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom dialog and open it with below line...

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
    PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, _, __) => CustomAlertDialog(), opaque: false),
);
```

The **opaque: false** will keep background transparent.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a new "page" with push state, the old "page" or state is disposed until you call `Navigator.pop(context)`. If you want to have a effect shown in the screenshot you provided, use a [dialog](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/SimpleDialog-class.html).

Comment: Is there any way we can make widget's background transparent, so that user can able to see prev screen content?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: There's always a way to control every single pixel.  You may just have to write a custom widget.  But keep in mind the source code to all the other widgets is just a keystroke or two away!